# If A is a stronger acid than B then is B necessarily a stronger base than A?

Tags: acid-base

It seems like this must be true. So if it is could someone please prove this?

Comment: I'd say it's not true in general. Unless in the 'stronger base' part of your sentence you actually mean the _conjugate anions_ of each acid. Then it's true by definition: if the forward reaction (acid going to proton+anion) is more favourable, the backward reaction (conjugated base catching a proton and forming the acid) must be less favourable.

Comment: No I don't mean the conjugates. As an example, water is a stronger acid than ammonia but ammonia is a stronger base than water.

Comment: Then no, I confirm what I stated earlier, it's not a general rule.

Comment: BTW,  interesting to see how some people feel completely unashamed securing a nice +5 by just copying someone else's pre-existing comment and posting it as an original answer.

Comment: @user6376297 I certainly didn't mean to copy your comment as an answer and I'm sorry it seems that way. It's hard to see how an answer could be anything else, however, since the answer to the question is basically "yes" or "no". You'll also notice that my answer was meant to copy the form of OP's comment. I'm not even giving an explanation. Only a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general this is not true.

For instance, water is a stronger acid than ethane and is also a stronger base than ethane.